# A preposition for "occur"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wrote:

> Bending can occur **(on vs. in)** the middle frame during operation due to the high temperature of the furnace and [the?] axial strains. An excessive bending can cause the pallet car to be engaged with the underlying structure, (**and increase vs. thereby increasing**) the force required to rotate the conveyor.

The *occur* usually comes with "in", but here should I use "on" or "in"? I think, I saw "on" in a related document.

I also don't know to use "and increase" or "thereby increasing" in the second part. I think "and increase" doesn't coney that it is the result of the first sentence. if yes, then what is the structure for "thereby ...ing"? did I use it correctly?

And finally, I wrote "*the force required to rotate the conveyor*". I maybe could write it as "*the required force for rotating the conveyor*". are they different? which of these is better?

I yet don't know if "bending" is countable or uncountable or both and if I used the cases correctly!

Comment: We must ask, what gets bent?  The frame?

Comment: You would want to say "to *become* engaged".

Comment: @Yes the frame of a pallet car may gets bent. the front view of pallet car is like `---------`, which turns to `__--==--__`

Answer (score 1):

The more natural preposition to use is **of**:

> Bending **of** the middle frame can occur...

Bending is a process like washing, so it is uncountable. You should say

> Excessive bending... - *without the **An***

**thereby increasing** is definitely the better of the two options, as [thereby](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thereby) makes it clear that one event a consequence of the other, or simply put **increasing**.

**force required** is the correct word order, as the correct meaning is given by a reduction of

> ...increasing the force [that is] required to rotate the conveyor

Comment: Thanks, then you mean all processes ( *...ing*) are uncountable?!

Comment: For the first sentence, it is the first time I want to emphasize where bending can occur in a pallet car. But I feel to say, "bending of the middle frame" makes it like an aforementioned subject.

Comment: Strictly processes, yes. The product of a process may be countable: drawing -> drawings. Also, -ing words that represent movements are countable, like **comings and goings** or **meanderings**.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I really do think that what's being bent has to be next to **bending**, not next to **occur**. It's that separation of verb and 'object' that got you into trouble with prepositions, because you felt that **occur** needed the preposition.

Comment: The comments to my [other question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103623/when-do-we-use-gerund-after-and) says, **and increasing** is totally wrong, though only "increasing" or "thereby increasing" works.

Comment: @Ahmad, my mistake. Having re-read the entire sentence, I see that **and increasing** would not work. Stick with **thereby increasing**, or just **increasing**. I have updated my answer.