# When do we use gerund after "and"?

Tags: conjunctions, gerunds

I know after prepositions a gerund is used. Today in [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/a-preposition-for-occur?noredirect=1#comment205020_103607) I wrote

> Excessive bending can cause the pallet car to become engaged with the underlying structure, **and increase** the force required to rotate the conveyor.

[I was suggested](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/103610/11569) to use either **thereby increasing** or **and increasing**. However I don't know the rule for "and".

Here I wrote:

> The next stage is to detect bending **and measuring** the degree of bending.

Should it be:

- and measure
- and to measure
- and measuring

I would like to know when to use gerund after a conjunction word and when not!

Comment: Your "Here what I wrote" sentence is totally ungrammatical. One valid combination is *The next stage is to detect bending and [to] measure the degree of bending* (where ***to*** is optional). In principle,  *The next stage is detecting bending and measuring the degree of bending* could be called "grammatical", but it's hopelessly awkward. Much more natural would be *The next stage is to detect and measure the degree of bending,* but that obviously doesn't address the specific syntax you're asking about.

Comment: Structurally, you first example is *Bending can cause A **and** [can] increase B*. Whoever suggested ***and increasing*** doesn't know English very well. If you change ***and*** to ***thereby*** you're completely changing the syntactic structure, in which case only ***increasing*** will be valid, but you should note that this is NOT a "gerund" usage (a gerund is a verb used *as a **noun***, but here it's just a continuous verb form).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know what is exactly gerund and call any verb with "ing" gerund. In my first sentence, "thereby increasing" is correct, because it is the result of the first sentence. But you say, it can't be "and increasing"? and just maybe only "increasing" after comma?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I provided the link to JavaLatte answer in the question. (*I was suggested...*)

Comment: You can certainly say things like *Governments may raise the tax on tobacco, **increasing** the cost of smoking*, in which context it would be fine to include ***thereby***.

Comment: At the end of the day, it seems to me both this and your previous question are really just proofreading. If we were looking at "generic" *structures*, I suspect what you really need to know is the difference between *Governments may raise the tax on tobacco, **[thereby] increasing** the cost of smoking* as opposed to *Governments may raise the tax on tobacco **and increase** the cost of smoking* (that second version is unlikely, but could well be understood to mean something significantly different).

Comment: @FumbleFingers No! that has nothing with proofreading, specially this question. In the other question I asked multiple specific questions. Anyway, the answer to my question said "*If you decided to use 'and', it would also be followed by the participle increasing rather than the simple present/infinitive increase.*", it made me to ask this question, because as I said I got confused when to use "and increasing" and when "and increase"... I have no problem with only "increasing" or "thereby increasing"... That answer made me doubtful about "and increasing"

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice the bit where Javalatte *appears* to be suggesting you could use ***and increasing***. I'm sure if he/she thinks about it more carefully they'll agree this isn't what was meant, and/or you've misunderstood the point being made.